# splitting large dataset to use langchain

Tags: nlp, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

I am currently using langchain to make a conversational chatbot from an existing data among this data I have some excel and csv files that contain a huge datasets.
My question is how can I handle the case when I want loading this kind of data to the vector database? is good to split it row by row to maintain the meaning of the data but I am afraid to crush the database or load it as it is without spliting.

Comment: there are different loaders in langhcain. each already splits the data. you chould check the docs and see if the default splitting is best for your dataset

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are looking for is the [csv_loader](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/csv) at least to start off. But from there you are going to want to (as you said) load it into a vector database. Chroma should do this just fine. Here is an example of what that might look like:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
loader = CSVLoader(file_path="./example_data/mlb_teams_2012.csv")
data = loader.load()
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(data, embeddings)
```

Using this, langchain will read in your CSV's and then Croma will embed the documents and store them locally in a .chroma folder. With this setup, then when you query the data you can ask Chroma to only load the CSV entries with the relevant data and not overwhelm whatever you are feeding it into.

Comment: Thank you, The problem which I encountered in my situation is I have to load the dataset in a vector database like chroma or opensearch for persistence purposes then query it each time I ask the chatbot. The csv loader you have already mentioned it loads data row by row, assuming we have a big dataset of billions of rows this behavior may crash the database. So my question is there any alternative?